# Tensorflow dataset repeat and model accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset that I am trying to train with. I want to pick random rows from the entire dataset for each batch. I don't want to repeat the exact same batch over and over again.

The problem I have is every time I run the code, the accuracy starts off low and then increases. I think it is because it is training on a single batch each run. If it was training on the full dataset, the accuracy would not reset every time I run the program. I could be wrong. It could be that my model is not being saved but I do save/restore it.

Run 1

```
Iter= 2000, Average Loss= 0.105903, Average Accuracy= 79.21%
Iter= 4000, Average Loss= 0.090152, Average Accuracy= 73.22%
Iter= 6000, Average Loss= 0.100107, Average Accuracy= 85.10%
Iter= 8000, Average Loss= 0.106910, Average Accuracy= 95.63%
```

Run 2

```
Iter= 2000, Average Loss= 0.105059, Average Accuracy= 81.15%
Iter= 4000, Average Loss= 0.105170, Average Accuracy= 92.25%
Iter= 6000, Average Loss= 0.106881, Average Accuracy= 95.68%
```

Run 3

```
Iter= 2000, Average Loss= 0.102585, Average Accuracy= 79.52%
Iter= 4000, Average Loss= 0.079520, Average Accuracy= 75.09%
Iter= 6000, Average Loss= 0.077820, Average Accuracy= 73.63%
```

Code

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_tfrecords)
dataset = dataset.map(parse)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

saver.restore(session, model_location)

while step < training_iters:
    features, one_hot_labels = session.run(next_element)
    _, acc, loss, logits = session.run([optimizer, accuracy, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: features, y: one_hot_labels})

    loss_total += loss
    acc_total += acc
    if (step+1) % display_step == 0:
        saver.save(session, model_location)
        print("Iter= " + str(step+1) + ", Average Loss= " + \
              "{:.6f}".format(loss_total/display_step) + ", Average Accuracy= " + \
              "{:.2f}%".format(100*acc_total/display_step))
        acc_total = 0
        loss_total = 0
    step += 1
```

Comment: How many elements are in the dataset? If it is much larger than the `buffer_size` argument to `dataset.shuffle()`, it's possible that the training will overfit to the specific order of training examples, so consider increasing the buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problem with what you describe. Naturally as the network learns its accuracy increases. Your code looks to properly save and restore the network between runs too. The third run might either be overfitting or your learning rate might be too high and it makes the model diverge or oscillate. Not sure if you're using learning rate annealment? Also, for clarity, I usually restore the training iteration number as well.